# How to properly send the nested object references to functions?

Tags: javascript

I have an object `car` that contains sub-objects:

```
var car = {
    bumper: {
        nodes: [[x,y,z],[x,y,z],[...], ... ],
        faces: [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[...], ... ]
    },

    //more objects

    //references to car parts
    parts: [this.bumper, this.wheel, ... ]
};
```

The references to these objects are then stored in a `car` member array `parts`. Then when I try to access these objects via the `parts` references in the next function:

```
var drawParts = function(car.parts)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < car.parts.length; ++i)
    {
        drawFaces(car.parts[i].faces, car.parts[i].nodes);
    }
};
```

the error occurs in that the expression `car.parts[i]` is evaluated as `undefined`.

Could somebody guide me on how to send the `bumper` object arrays `faces` and `nodes` to the `drawFaces()` function the proper way?

Comment: Here's a bin of it working. Instead of referencing an array of parts, I added a function that gets all of the nested objects inside of the car object. https://jsbin.com/yapuqupece/edit?html,output

Comment: Note that this will grab all keys off the car, if you're storing meta-data this won't work as nicely. I'm just console.log ing the results out